# Capybara Around Hook to test several envinroments

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm writing some tests for a webpage that I'd like to run in several environments. The idea is that the test will run in one, then repeat in the next. The two environments are preview and uat.

I've written an `Around` hook to set the environment variables. Below:

```
Around do |scenario, block|
  def test_envs
    chosen_env = ENV['test_env'] || 'preview'
    chosen_env.split(',').map(&:strip)
  end
  test_envs.each do |test_env|
    $base_url = "https://#{test_env}.webpage.com"
  end
  block.call
end
```

I have then written a method to execute the navigation step:

```
def navigate_to(path)
  visit $base_url + path
end
```

My Scenario step_definition is:

```
navigate_to '/login'
```

The tests will work in either environment, Preview by default or UAT if I set `test_env=uat`

However, I was aiming to set `test_env=preview,uat` and have them run consecutively in both environments.

Is there something obvious that I've missed here?

Thanks

Comment: Should the block call be inside each ? As I see the each loop on environments is only setting the base_url, but not doing anything beyond it.

Comment: that was it, well spotted.  Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Another way I have dealt with this in the past is to create a single rake task to run the tests on each environment. That way the environment and hooks are completely agnostic and cleanly lined up. Just in case you want to try an alternate

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it's the 'parallel' aspect that you're asking about.

Rspec can be used with parallel tests (the [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) gem) but I wouldn't be so sure that calling something like `3.times { blk.call }` in an around hook will run each block in parallel.

An alternative may be do so some metaprogramming with your example definitions, i.e.

```
  test_envs.each do |env_name|
    it "does something in #{env_name}" do
      # do something with the specific environment
    end
  end
```

Now, I haven't actually used this gem and I don't know for sure it would work. I think the simplest solution may be to just write a wrapper script to call the tests

```
  # run_tests.rb

  environments = ENV["TEST_ENV"]&.split(",") || []\
  filename = ENV["filename"]
  environments.each do |env_name|
    Thread.new do
      system <<-SH
        env TEST_ENV=#{env_name} bundle exec rspec #{filename}
      SH
    end
  end
```

Running it like `env TEST_ENV=foo,bar ruby run_tests.rb` would call the following commands in their own threads:

- `env TEST_ENV=foo bundle exec rspec`
- `env TEST_ENV=bar bundle exec rspec`

I like this approach because it means you don't have to touch your existing test code.

Comment: Hi Max, what I was trying to achieve wasn't quite a parallel run.  I was writing it to run a scenario in one environment, then repeat in the next environment without needing to specify the environment(s) every time.  Unfortunately, the machines we are working on at the moment are pretty poor and they're not too great with parallel running.  Hoping to get upgrades soon :)